# How to get wildcard value from mqtt topic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho

Let's say I've several devices each having a temperature. All messages related to device temperature are published on topics `device/1/temerature`, `device/2/temperature`, etc. . I handle all messages published on this topic with Python paho-mqtt with a callback function which uses a wildcard expression `client.message_on_callback_add("device/+/temperature", ...)`. Is there a way to get the value of the wildcard expression, here `+` directly (w.o. need for parsing of `msg.topic`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the callback includes the topic the message was published to.

It is up to you to extract what ever information you need from the topic.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking to extract the client id from the topic. The callback functions will have clientid as part of the callback. Pleaes check the functions in the below URL.

https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#callbacks

If you are using the default callback function on the message received, you will be able to get the client as a separate parameter.

Comment: No it won't. The client id of the publisher is NOT included in the message. The attached client object is the local paho client object. There is no way to find the publishers client id unless it is encoded in the topic or message body.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I was of the opinion the requirement is the current client who has subscribed.  However. the alternate is writing the application behind a Broker that provides on_message option.  where you will be getting the meta info of the publisher.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you can get the subscribed topic when the message arrived. You can split topic to get wildcard characters from subscribed topic.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe("device/+/temperature")
    client.message_callback_add("device/+/temperature", handler("device/+/temperature"))
    
def handler(subscribed_topic):
    wildcard_expression = subscribed_topic
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload), wildcard_expression)
    return on_message
    
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(<mqtt broker url>, 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Just posting code with no description of how it works or how it actually solves the OP's question is practically useless. Also this doesn't help the OP get the value represented by the `+` which is what was asked.

Comment: Thanks. I've added description.

Comment: But it still doesn't solve the problem the OP asked about.

Comment: i think it solves. "Is there a way to get the value of the wildcard expression". msg object doesn't contain subscribed topic. Contains only published topic (device/1/temperature,device/2/temperature,etc). But passing subscribed topic as a parameter to handler function enables us accessing it when the message arrived.

Comment: They are explicitly asking for the value that the `+` matches with, not the `+` it's self.

Comment: I mean it's possible to get the wildcard expression value although msg.topic doesn't contain it. The main issue in the problem is to be able to get the subscribed topic(device/+/temperature) when message arrived. We also have the published topic in msg.topic(device/1/temperature). After that we can get the value of + easily by splitting and matching these strings.